# Use generics to simplify the calls

Tags: java, generics

I have 2 methods that I use for making the web call provided below:

```
    protected HttpResponse<String> getResponseAsString(String url, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, Object> reportForm, String reportName) throws UnirestException {
        return Unirest.get(url).headers(headers).queryString(reportForm).asString();
    }

    protected HttpResponse<InputStream> getResponseAsInputStream(String url, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, Object> reportForm, String reportName) throws UnirestException {
        return Unirest.get(url).headers(headers).queryString(reportForm).asBinary();
    }
```

So I receive the calls like this:

```
HttpResponse<String> value = getResponseAsString(...........)
```

Is it possible to use generics to create a single call for this purpose and would it have adverse effects considering the performance?

Also, how would be the receive calls look syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create one single method that returns:

```
Unirest.get(url).headers(headers).queryString(reportForm)
```

And let the caller decide whether to call `asString` or `asBinary` on the result, depending on their needs.

```
// please replace "SomeType" with the return type of "queryString"
protected SomeType getResponse(String url, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, Object> reportForm, String reportName) throws UnirestException {
    return Unirest.get(url).headers(headers).queryString(reportForm);
}

// usage:
HttpResponse<String> value = getResponseAsString(...........).asString();
// or
HttpResponse<InputStream> value = getResponseAsString(...........).asBinary();
```

If you don't want to expose `SomeType`, then you could create a wrapper around it, and only provide `asString` and `asBinary` methods for conversion to `HttpResponse<String>` and `HttpResponse<InputStream>`.

Generics isn't suitable here, as your method does different things on *two* unrelated types. Generics work best when your method does the same thing no matter what type it is given, such as `Collections.sort`, `Arrays.asList` etc.

Here's what I would have done if I were forced to use generics. It's not pretty...

```
protected <T> HttpResponse<T> getResponse(Class<T> clazz, String url, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, Object> reportForm, String reportName) throws UnirestException {
    SomeType queryString = Unirest.get(url).headers(headers).queryString(reportForm);
    if (clazz == String.class) {
        // ugly unchecked cast warnings here!
        return (T)queryString.asString();
    } else if (clazz == InputStream.class) {
        return (T)queryString.asBinary();
    } else {
        return null; // or throw an IllegalArgumentException 
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted but I’m still interested to see any generics answer

Comment: @ChakladerAsfakArefe Added a generics solution. It's not pretty, and I don't think there could be one prettier than a non-generic solution. Generics simply isn't the right tool in this case.